# Fitting a data with asymmetric errors on both axis in Python

Tags: python, scipy, regression, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I have data in the form of 6 parameters: x, y, x+ error, x- error, y+ error, y- error. I want to find the best fit for this dataset. I'm trying to use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` but it does not let me choose the error in the data (I think). I tried to figure out a way and I found that there is a function called sigma in `curve_fit` that does something similar but it's only for error on one axis. Is there any way I can find the best fit for the data while considering the error in the data points?

I want to fit those red scatter dots in the following plot:
[image]

Here is the code for scipy fit without error bars in case it helps:

```python
#Import the Data
obs0x,xerr0_plus,xerr0_minus,obs0y,yerr_plus,yerr_minus=np.loadtxt("Mhratioz6",unpack='true')
    
#define the function to fit
def func(x, a, b):
    return (np.log10(a)+(b*(x-12))+np.log10(10**(8+c)))
    return ((x/1e12)**a)*(b)*(10**(8+c))
    return a+(b*x)

#define the data to be fit
xdata=np.log10(obs0x)
ydata=np.log10(obs0y)
 p0=[-1,1.65,0]

#Fit for the parameters a, b, c of the function func:
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
print("[a,b]=",popt)

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.loglog(10**xdata, 10**func(xdata, *popt), 'r-',label='scipy fit')
#plt.loglog(m, func(m, *popt), 'r-',label='Scipy-fit')
plt.scatter(obs0x,obs0y,s=2)
plt.ylim(1e6,1e11)
plt.xlim(1e11,1e14)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title("z=0 Observations")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

`curve_fit` can handle fit just with uncertainty on the y axis: It is unable to perform fit if you have uncertainty both on the x axis and y axis.
If you want to manage noise on the x axis, you have to use odr.

```
from scipy import odr

#Firstly you have to create a RealData object

data = odr.RealData(x_var,y_var,sx = x_err, sy = y_err)

#Model object

quad_model = odr.Model(test_func)

#test_func is the function you want to use as model for your fitting

#Set up ODR with the model and data

odr = odr.ODR(data, quad_model,beta0 =[])

#beta0 is a list which contains the initial value of the parameters 

#Run the regression.
out = odr.run()

out.beta
#out.beta is a list which contains the values of the parameters popped out from the fitting

out.sd_beta

#out.sd_beta is a list which contains the values of the errors of the parameters
```